# windows - allowing remote desktop machine to access local files

Tags: windows, windows-xp, remote-desktop, administration, system-administration

currently i have two machines A and B... both are running WinXP.

I am on machine A and using mstsc to connect to machine B. Now, how can i see from machine B the cdrom, usb, disk drives of machine A? even more if connect any usb to machine A can it be automatically detected by machine B also?

Comment: This is definitely an IT question; I have a difficult time grasping how it is programming related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> cdrom, usb, disk drives:
>   1. NetBIOS or OpenSSH/SSHFS.
>   usb
>   Try some USB redirector to access non-storage USB devices